# How to use CheckBoxList and DropdownList in MVC4 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html-helper, checkboxlist

I have to use @Html.CheckBoxListFor<> or @Html.DropdownListFor<>.I am confused about how to use these helper class in View whild I am using List for Model Binding.

What is the Right and Easiest way to Bind List into CheckBoxList and DropdownList.

**In Model:**

```
public class SampleViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Responsible> AvailableResponsibles { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Responsible> SelectedResponsibles { get; set; }
        public PostedResponsibles PostedResponsibles { get; set; }
        Responsible objResponsible = new Responsible();
        public SampleViewModel GetResponsiblesInitialModel()
        {
            //setup properties
            var model = new SampleViewModel();
            var selectedResponsibles = new List<Responsible>();

            //setup a view model
            model.AvailableResponsibles = objResponsible.GetAll().ToList();
            model.SelectedResponsibles = selectedResponsibles;
            return model;
        }
    }
public class Responsible
    {
        //Integer value of a checkbox
        public int Id { get; set; }

        //String name of a checkbox
        public string Name { get; set; }

        //Boolean value to select a checkbox
        //on the list
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

        //Object of html tags to be applied
        //to checkbox, e.g.:'new{tagName = "tagValue"}'
        public object Tags { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Responsible> GetAll()
        {
            return new List<Responsible> {
                              new Responsible {Name = "Apple", Id = 1 },
                              new Responsible {Name = "Banana", Id = 2},
                              new Responsible {Name = "Cherry", Id = 3},
                              new Responsible {Name = "Pineapple", Id = 4},
                              new Responsible {Name = "Grape", Id = 5},
                              new Responsible {Name = "Guava", Id = 6},
                              new Responsible {Name = "Mango", Id = 7}
                            };
        }

    }

    public class PostedResponsibles
    {
        //this array will be used to POST values from the form to the controller
        public string[] ResponsibleIds { get; set; }
    }
```

**And View Is:**

```
<tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model=>model.Responsible)
                </td>
                <td>
                  @Html.CheckBoxListFor(model => model.PostedResponsibles.ResponsibleIds,
                                  model => model.AvailableResponsibles,
                                  Responsible => Responsible.Id,
                                  Responsible => Responsible.Name,
                                  model => model.SelectedResponsibles)

                </td>
            </tr>
```

Currently I am using Nuget Packege but it is little bit confusing and hard to use.Suggest me any other to achieve this one.

Comment: Browse http://codeproject.com/Articles/292050/… Site ,It really helpful Article.

Comment: See this;  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422718/how-do-you-properly-create-a-multiselect-select-using-the-dropdownlist-helper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depend on your UI requirement. if you need a drop down list then use that.

CheckBoxList is not out of the box helper, it is a custom helper.

You can find more details of the helper (CheckBoxList) from here [**Code Project**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/292050/CheckBoxList-For-A-missing-MVC-extension)

Regarding Drop down please refer to [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor(v=vs.108).aspx). It can be overloaded in multiple ways.

Here are the available [**ASP.NET MVC helpers**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper(v=vs.108).aspx)

Comment: Thanks,I browse http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/292050/CheckBoxList-For-A-missing-MVC-extension Site ,It really helpful Article.

Answer (score 2):

1. Step Install package using package manager

   ```
   Install-Package MvcCheckBoxList
   ```
2. Add **Fruit.cs**

   ```cs
   namespace CheckBoxListForApp.Models
   {
     public class Fruit
     {
         public int Id { get;set;}
         public string Name { get;set; }  
         public bool IsSelected{get;set;}
         public object Tags { get;set;}
     }
   }
   ```
3. Add **FruitViewModel.cs**

   ```cs
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   namespace CheckBoxListForApp.Models
   {
     public class FruitViewModel
     {
       public IEnumerable<Fruit> AvailableFruits { get; set; }
       public IEnumerable<Fruit> SelectedFruits { get; set; }
       public PostedFruits PostedFruits { get; set; }
     }
   }
   ```
4. Add **PostedFruits.cs**

   ```cs
   namespace CheckBoxListForApp.Models
   {
       /// <summary>
       /// for Helper class to make posting back selected values easier
       /// </summary>
       public class PostedFruits
       {
           //this array will be used to POST values from the form to the controller
           public string[] FruitIds { get; set; }
       }
   }
   ```
5. Add **HomeController.cs**

   ```cs
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Globalization;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Web.Mvc;
   using CheckBoxListForApp.Models;

   namespace CheckBoxListForApp.Controllers
   {
       public class HomeController : Controller
       {

           [HttpGet]
           public ActionResult Index()
           {
               return View(GetFruitsInitialModel());
           }


           [HttpPost]
           public ActionResult Index(PostedFruits postedFruits)
           {
               return View(GetFruitsModel(postedFruits));
           }

           private FruitViewModel GetFruitsModel(PostedFruits postedFruits)
           {

               var model = new FruitViewModel();
               var selectedFruits = new List<Fruit>();
               var postedFruitIds = new string[0];
               if (postedFruits == null) postedFruits = new PostedFruits();

               // if a view model array of posted fruits ids exists
               // and is not empty,save selected ids
               if (postedFruits.FruitIds != null && postedFruits.FruitIds.Any())
               {
                   postedFruitIds = postedFruits.FruitIds;
               }

               // if there are any selected ids saved, create a list of fruits
               if (postedFruitIds.Any())
               {
                 selectedFruits = FruitRepository.GetAll()
                  .Where(x => postedFruitIds.Any(s => x.Id.ToString().Equals(s)))
                  .ToList();
               }


               model.AvailableFruits = FruitRepository.GetAll().ToList();
               model.SelectedFruits = selectedFruits;
               model.PostedFruits = postedFruits;
               return model;
           }

           private FruitViewModel GetFruitsInitialModel()
           {

               var model = new FruitViewModel();
               var selectedFruits = new List<Fruit>();


               model.AvailableFruits = FruitRepository.GetAll().ToList();
               model.SelectedFruits = selectedFruits;
               return model;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
6. Add **FruitRepository.cs**

   ```cs
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;

   namespace CheckBoxListForApp.Models
   {
       /// <summary>
       /// work as fruit repository
       /// </summary>
       public static class FruitRepository
       {
           /// <summary>
           /// for get fruit for specific id
           /// </summary>
           public static Fruit Get(int id)
           {
               return GetAll().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id.Equals(id));
           }

           /// <summary>
           /// for get all fruits
           /// </summary>
           public static IEnumerable<Fruit> GetAll()
           {
               return new List<Fruit> {
                                 new Fruit {Name = "Apple", Id = 1 },
                                 new Fruit {Name = "Banana", Id = 2},
                                 new Fruit {Name = "Cherry", Id = 3},
                                 new Fruit {Name = "Pineapple", Id = 4},
                                 new Fruit {Name = "Grape", Id = 5},
                                 new Fruit {Name = "Guava", Id = 6},
                                 new Fruit {Name = "Mango", Id = 7}
                               };
           }
       }
   }
   ```
7. Add **Index.cshtml**

   ```html
   @using MvcCheckBoxList.Model
   @model CheckBoxListForApp.Models.FruitViewModel

   @{
       ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
   }

   <section class="checkBoxListFor">
       <p>
           <label>Please Select Fruits:</label>
           @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
           {
               @Html.CheckBoxListFor(model => model.PostedFruits.FruitIds,
                                     model => model.AvailableFruits,
                                     fruit => fruit.Id,
                                     fruit => fruit.Name,
                                     model => model.SelectedFruits,
                                     Position.Horizontal)
               <input class="green" type="submit" 
                         value="POST to Controller" />
           }
       </p>
   </section>
   ```