# HTML CheckBoxListFor in MVC4 returning null values

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using HTML CheckBoxListFor extension to display list with check box and retrieve selected values. Issue is I am getting null values in my controller.

View Code

```
@Html.CheckBoxListFor(model => model.PostedStyles, model => model.styles, style => style.Value,style =>style.Text, model => model.selStyles,Position.Horizontal)
```

ViewModel

```
public IEnumerable<CheckboxStyle> styles { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<CheckboxStyle> selStyles { get; set; }
public PostedStyles PostedStyles { get; set; }
```

Classes

```
public class CheckboxStyle
    {
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

public class PostedStyles
    {
        public string[] StyleIds { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller Code:

Intial Load

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {

            return View(GetStylesInitialModel());
}
 private CreateLabelViewModel GetStylesInitialModel()
        {
            //setup properties
            var model = new CreateLabelViewModel();
            var selectedFruits = new List<CheckboxStyle>();

            //setup a view model
            model.styles = StyleRepository.GetAll().ToList();
            model.selStyles = selectedFruits;
            return model;
        }
```

On Button Click

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GenerateLabels(PostedStyles postedStyles)
        {

            return View(GetStylesModel(postedStyles));
        }
```

I am getting null values in `postedStyles` above.

Checked a lot but didn't get anything relevant. Please advise.

Comment: check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19468666/how-to-use-checkboxlist-and-dropdownlist-in-mvc4-razor

Comment: Its there in CheckBoxStyle Class public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

U can refer to below link :

http://mvccbl.azurewebsites.net/

Hope this Helps...