# ListBoxFor MultiSelectList does not select values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm incredibly confused, because this seems like it should be simple but I can't get my `ListBox` to be populated with selected values. I've looked at several other answers and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

This is my model:

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Item> AllItems { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Item> SelectedItems { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This is my controller action:

```
public ActionResult ListBoxTest()
{
    var viewModel = new ItemViewModel()
    {
        AllItems = new List<Item>()
        {
            new Item()
            {
                Id = "1",
                Name = "Name1"
            },
            new Item()
            {
                Id = "2",
                Name = "Name2"
            }
        },
        SelectedItems = new List<Item>()
        {
            new Item()
            {
                Id = "1",
                Name = "Name1"
            }
        }
    };
    return this.View(viewModel);
}
```

And this is the line in my view (using a default MVC View template):

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedItems, new MultiSelectList(Model.AllItems, "Id", "Name", Model.SelectedItems.Select(s => s.Id)), new { multiple = "multiple"})
```

I've also tried omitting the selected values:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedItems, new MultiSelectList(Model.AllItems, "Id", "Name"), new { multiple = "multiple"})
```

And making the selected values a list:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedItems, new MultiSelectList(Model.AllItems, "Id", "Name", Model.SelectedItems.Select(s => s.Id).ToList()), new { multiple = "multiple"})
```

But no matter what I do, the list items are never selected. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422718/how-do-you-properly-create-a-multiselect-select-using-the-dropdownlist-helper

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot bind a `<select>` element to a collection of complex objects. A multiple select only posts back an array of simple values - the values of the selected options.

Your model needs to be

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Item> AllItems { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<int> SelectedItems { get; set; }
}
```

and in the controller

```
SelectedItems = new List<int>(){ 1 }
```

then using

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedItems, new SelectList(Model.AllItems, "Id", "Name")
```

will select the first option in the dropdownlist.

Note that the `ListBoxFor()` method sets `multiple="multiple"` so there is no need to set it again. In addition, Setting the last parameter of in the `SelectList()` (or `MultiSelectList()`) constructor is pointless. Its the value of the property your binding to which determines what is selected and internally the `ListBoxFor()` method ignores that parameter.

I would also suggest your property should be

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AllItems { get; set; }
```

so that you can simply use

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedItems, Model.AllItems)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works and makes sense. I wish some of these helpers had a more strict signature with stronger typed parameters and generics to make it easier to understand what each parameter is expecting.