# Drop down not allowing multiple selected values in MVC5

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu

this code does not allow me to select multiple items, how do I adjust it so that it can? How do I call the multiple selected items? The same way or a new way?  Another thing that concerns me is the design of the dropdown, is it possible to dropdown a list of checkbox items? but that's optional.

**Partial View:**

```
@model Website_Design.Models.Models


@{
    var x = Model.Stuff.Countries[0].Text;
    <p>@x</p>
}
```

**Index View:**

```
@model Website_Design.Models.Models

  <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>


@{
using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Stuff.CountryId, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Stuff.CountryId, Model.Stuff.Countries, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


}
<input type="button" value="Battle" id="battleButton" />

}

<!--THREE-->
<div id="pvDiv1"></div>

<script>
var Battle = '@Url.Action("Battle", "Home")';
//MVC FUNCTIONS
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#battleButton').click(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: Battle,

            //data: $('form').serialize() + '&' + $.param({ a: P1, b: P2 }),
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function(result) {
                $('#pvDiv1').html(result);
            }

        });
    });
});
```

**Controller:**

```
 public ActionResult Index(Models model)
    {

        model.Stuff = new Stuff();

        return View(model);
    }
```

**Model:**

```
public class Stuff
{
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Countries
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<SelectListItem>{
                                                   new SelectListItem{
                                                                             Text="India",
                                                                             Value = "1"
                                                                         },
                                                   new SelectListItem{
                                                                             Text="USA",
                                                                             Value = "2"
                                                                         },
                                                   new SelectListItem{
                                                                             Text="USA2",
                                                                             Value = "3"
                                                                         },
                                                   new SelectListItem{
                                                                             Text="US3",
                                                                             Value = "2"
                                                                         }
                                               };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DropDownListFor` helper cannot create a multi select list.  It only creates the regular `<select>` drop down box.

In HTML, the only "native" way of creating a select box which allows multiple selections is to use a `<select>` element with a `multiple` attribute, like so:

```
<select multiple="multiple">
 ....
</select>
```

There is a helper method for that called `ListBoxFor`

Regarding the design, you cannot really change much.  If you want the dropdown list to display checkboxes, you are out of luck - you'll have to roll your own using CSS/Javascript.

There's more info about the `ListBoxFor` helper here:
[How do you properly create a MultiSelect <select> using the DropdownList helper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422718/how-do-you-properly-create-a-multiselect-select-using-the-dropdownlist-helper)