# Set The selected Value of a Multiselect from Controller to View after submitting an invalid Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper

I am using a Multiselect DropDownList to generate a multiple `<select>` 
I was able to generate it and was working fine.

But If I try to submit it using the parameters:

1. Name = null
2. ObjAOption = [1,2] // assume I selected 2 options in my multiselect

ObjAOption will just select `option value='1'` instead of select options 1, and 2.

Is there any way I can get back the selected options and pass it back to my view by setting it in my controller? I would love to use HTML helper and not to use jQuery or javascript on this part.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult AddObjectA(AddModel am){
      if(ModelState.IsValid){
            //Save
      }
      else {
            am.ObjA = // new List of ObjectA with atleast 4 option
            return View("MyView",am);
      }
}
```

View:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ObjA, "Object A")
@Html.DropDownList("ObjAOption", new MultiSelectList(Model.ObjA, "Key", "Name"), "-- Select Object A--", new { @class = "custom-select custom-select-sm", multiple="" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ObjAOption, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Model:

```
public class AddModel {
        [Required]
        public String Name {get;set;}
        public IEnumerable<ObjectA> ObjA{ get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select at least one option")]
        public List<int>ObjAOption{ get; set; }
}

public class ObjectA {
        public int Key {get;set;}
        public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

I scrapped out my DropDownList and tried using ListBoxFor as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422718/how-do-you-properly-create-a-multiselect-select-using-the-dropdownlist-helper)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the helper `Hiddenfor` ? It generate a field that keep your element value, name and attribute :

View:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ObjA, "Object A")
@Html.DropDownList("ObjAOption", new MultiSelectList(Model.ObjA, "Key", "Name"), "-- Select Object A--", new { @class = "custom-select custom-select-sm", multiple="" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ObjAOption, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ObjAOption)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, it didn't work. as far as I know. HiddenFor creates an input type='hidden' element and binds the model property. I will edit the topic title to avoid further misunderstanding.